# Can I change Battle Sprites?

Tags: spiral-knights

Is there anyway for me to re-change the Battle Sprite I picked? I originally started out with the fire based one, but now I regret it because I solo the Clockworks most of the time.

Comment: Some asking around suggests that this will be a feature for a future patch.  Doesn't seem like you can as of yet, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't *change* your battle sprite.  However, you *can* buy more for 2000 energy each.

Answer (score -1):

You can currently.

In my opinion, Seraphynx is bad, Drakon is OK, and Maskeraith is great.

Comment: Could you please go into detail on HOW you change sprites rather than just say "you can"? Also, questions on arqade are for factual answers, not opinions.